# Is it a good idea to put on yellow dragon scale mail and go to town with a rubber chicken?

Tags: nethack

I haven't yet gotten yellow dragon scale and may not understand how it works.  Does it make you immune to turning to stone from cockatrices?  If so, would an ascension kit with other sources of reflection and magic resistance and a plan to use cockatrice corpses as weapons be a potentially good strategy?

Comment: Is that what they're calling cockatrices these days? Do they come with pulleys in the middle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you might have gotten some misinformation. [Yellow dragon scale mail](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Yellow_dragon_scale_mail) provides acid resistance, not stoning resistance. In fact, in vanilla Nethack it's not possible to achieve intrinsic or extrinsic stoning resistance at all, aside from polymorphing into a stoning-resistant monster. The confusion might be due to the fact that acidic monsters are useful as a way to prevent stoning (by eating their corpses).

Your idea of wielding a cockatrice corpse as a weapon is not an uncommon strategy, but you need to be wearing gloves at all times and you must be *extremely* careful, because there are [lots of ways that something can go wrong](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Cockatrice#Wearing_gloves_while_wielding_the_corpse_as_a_weapon). You may want to wear an amulet of life-saving just to be safe.

Comment: maybe yellow dragons are themselves stone resistant was the source of confusion?

Comment: @user62111 Good point!